# get column name matching regex pattern sql

Tags: php, sql, regex, pdo

I would like to get all columns within a table where the columns name is `foo32`. The number `32` could be any number. I have the following query that works fine excepts naturally it matches columns that do not only contain a number.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name =  'table1'
AND table_schema =  'database1'
AND column_name LIKE 'foo%'
```

Unfortunately the above query will match `foo12abc` and `fooCDE`.

I tried the following based on this page but it returned an empty result so something must be a miss.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name =  'table1'
AND table_schema =  'database1'
AND column_name REGEXP 'foo[^0-9]'
```

Example table:

```
foo1 | foo21 | fooABC | foo123ABC | foo19 | col12
_________________________________________________
// data ...
```

I would like the query to return columns `foo1`, `foo21` and `foo19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `foo[^0-9]` you're looking for `foo` followed by anything that is *not* `0-9` (the `^` at the beginning of a character class mean negation of what follows.

If you try `foo[0-9]` it should work (although it will catch things that don't begin with `foo` and that have an additional suffix).

This should be what you're looking for:

```
^foo\d+$
```

That translates to:

- `foo` right after the beginning of the table name (`^`)
- followed by one of more digits until the end of the table name (`$`)

Comment: Thanks. `foo[0-9]` works but like you say it also pulls in results that also have letters after the numbers. `^foo\d+$` returns an empty result?

Comment: It shouldn't return an empty result, but try without `^` and `$` to see what the result is like (basically: `foo\d+`).